# Anonymous disability survey - disclose disability that does not require accommodation?

Tags: united-states, disability

I have a stamina disability which I am currently able to manage in a way that does not require accommodation at work. I started at my current position a year and a half ago and did not disclose during hiring.

I have been running under keeping it under wraps unless I have a flare that requires accommodation. My employer is large and recently sent out an anonymous survey asking for self-identification of disabilities. Is there any reason to disclose in this format?

Comment: @Kilisi Formal diagnosis is POTS (Postural Orthostatic Tachycardia Syndrome) and I just get tired way more easily than normal for someone my age and physical health. First debilitating brain fog and difficulty concentrating, then dizziness and physical weakness, then if I am really stubborn about 'pushing through it' physical pain such as shooting pain down an arm or frequent leg cramps. No socializing outside of work or my spreadsheets stop making sense. Have to sit down to chop veggies or my brain won't form database queries the next day.

Comment: Have they stated what the purpose of the survey is? If so, do you support that purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends if you want it known or not that you have this condition. The thing with anonymous surveys is that quite often they're not anonymous at all.

I've seen a person berated and later sacked for badmouthing the CEO in an 'anonymous' survey asking for feedback on the company. And been privy to the contents of others which I could easily have worked out the people if I was nosy. I'm not saying your survey isn't truly anonymous.

I don't see any advantage to you disclosing it anonymously or otherwise since realistically it should have been disclosed a year and a half ago if at all. To me it's a risk for nothing.